# Passenger/nginx not loading Sinatra app

Tags: nginx, sinatra, passenger, rack

I'm trying to run a few Sinatra apps under sub-uri's, but it seems that Passenger isn't picking them up as Rack applications.

From the nginx-error log: 403 error, `directory index of "/web/archive/sites/archive/app1/" is forbidden`. If I place `index.html` in that directory, that HTML file renders.

The apps run fine with `rackup` on my local machine, so I feel the application code is irrelevant. I have also SSH'd in as both the nginx user (`user nginx` at the top of the nginx config), and as the `archive` user, which is the user used to deploy all of these applications, and which owns all of the directories and files. I have no problem navigating to any of these files with either user.

Also, this setup works fine if I move it over to a subdomain, like `archive.domain.com`, and then have the app symlinks live right in `/web/archive/sites` (rather than `/web/archive/sites/archive`), and otherwise use pretty much the same nginx config, which is why I don't believe this is a permissions issue.

**nginx config**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;

    location /archive {
        root /web/archive/sites;
        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_base_uri /app1;
        passenger_base_uri /app2
    }
}
```

**directory structure**

```
/web
  |
  +-- archive/
       |
       +-- sites/
       |    |
       |    +-- archive/
       |         |
       |         +-- app1 -> /web/archive/apps/app1/current/public
       |         |
       |         +-- app2 -> /web/archive/apps/app2/current/public 
       |
       +-- apps/
            |
            +-- app1/
            |    |
            |    +-- current/
            |    |
            |    +-- public/
            |    |
            |    +-- config.ru
            |
            +-- app2/
                 |
                 +-- (same as app1/)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `passenger_base_uri` together with the `root` in your configuration example do not match with the directory structure (e.g `/web/archive/sites/app1` vs `/web/archive/sites/archive/app1`). As far as I understand Passenger does not consider the location but only `root` and `passenger_base_uri`.

Try changing the configuration into

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;

    location /archive {
        root /web/archive/sites/archive;
        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_base_uri /app1;
        passenger_base_uri /app2
    }
}
```